# DNS is not propagating even after 48 hours on GoDaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

I have a domain name called `currykitchen.se` which was on another provider. I transferred to GoDaddy and they set up all DNS records and said it would take 24 to 48 hr. However, my site is still not working. I don’t know what the error is. Even GoDaddy tech guys don’t have any solution. They said it is a problem with my ISP. But it is not because I even tried to open that site on my phone by using phone data but the problem was the same. I even asked my friend to open the site, and the problem was the same for them.

Domain name is `currykitchen.se`.

```
Type    Name            Value                               TTL
A       @               92.204.218.48                       10800 seconds
A       admin           92.204.218.48                       10800 seconds
A       mail            92.204.218.48                       10800 seconds
CNAME   cpanel          @                                   10800 seconds
CNAME   webdisk         @                                   10800 seconds
CNAME   webdisk.admin   @                                   10800 seconds
CNAME   whm             @                                   10800 seconds
CNAME   www             @                                   10800 seconds
CNAME   www.admin       @                                   10800 seconds
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour
NS      @               ns39.domaincontrol.com              1 Hour  
NS      @               ns40.domaincontrol.com              1 Hour  
SOA     @               Primary nameserver: ns39.domaincontrol.com. 1 Hour
```

Answer (score 2):

You have broken DNSSEC setup. There is a DS record at `se` nameservers but you don't have any (and matching) DNSKEY entries at your nameservers:

```
vesemir:~> dig @f.ns.se currykitchen.se ds +short
12412 8 1 56C72723B507F1EAB757A2ACDE5B8290213DB57F
12412 8 2 6AE440ADABCB267F61CDB2DEDAB5B49F6865E4F9A033DAD99463F9FB C91D6CBD
vesemir:~> dig @ns39.domaincontrol.com currykitchen.se dnskey +cd

; <<>> DiG 9.11.13-RedHat-9.11.13-6.el8_2.1 <<>> @ns39.domaincontrol.com currykitchen.se dnskey +cd
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50879
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1472
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;currykitchen.se.               IN      DNSKEY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
currykitchen.se.        600     IN      SOA     ns39.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. 2020112201 28800 7200 604800 600

;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 2603:5:21d1::14#53(2603:5:21d1::14)
;; WHEN: nie lis 22 13:54:06 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 115
```

Validating resolvers are rightfully rejecting your unsigned responses.

You probably should remove DNSSEC info at your registrar first and re-establish new DNSSEC keys as the second step and re-add matching DS entries as the third step.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did it but it will take time 24 to 48 hrs. I hope this time it will work.